# How to unit test express route with passport authenticate

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mocha.js, passport.js

How can one unit test an express router that is dependent on passport authentication to call the helper methods?

I'm new to express unit testing and I've seen a lot of code that actually hits the server to call the method. But would that not make it an integration test? This ultimately comes down to my lack of understanding on the best practices on express unit testing.

I've tried to just mock out the passport but that didn't work because I need to get to the callbacks. I've also tried using rewire and just try to test the helper methods and that didn't seem to work either, I think, because file is wrapped in module.export.

Any help here would be much appreciated.

**File I'm trying to unit test:**

```
module.exports = function (inject) {
var router = require('express').Router();
var app = inject.app;

return router.get('/', app.passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false }), [editContentCheck, getUser]);

function editContentCheck(req,res,next) {
    if(req.authInfo.scope.indexOf('readOwnUser') == -1) {
        res.statusCode = 403;
        return res.end('Forbidden');
    }
    return next();
}

function getUser(req, res) {

    var authHeader = req.headers.authorization.split(' ');
    var token = authHeader[1];
    var models = require('../models');

    models.AccessToken.getAccessToken(token,function(err,tokenObj) {
        models.User.getUser(tokenObj.userId, function(err, user) {
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
            res.send(JSON.stringify(user));
        });
    });

 }
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this repository, it has all You want: https://github.com/num8er/alttab-nodejs-challenge

Also a look at example and implement it as You wish:

1)server.js :

```
var 
  http = require('http'),
  app = require('./app'); // app.js file

http.createServer(app).listen(8080);
```

2)app.js :

```
var
  express = require('express'),
  app = express();

app.use(require('./routes')); // routes.js file

module.exports = app;
```

3)routes.js :

```
var router = require('express').Router();

function editContentCheck(req,res,next) {}
function getUser(req, res) {}

router.get('/posts', app.passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false }), [editContentCheck, getUser]);

module.exports = router;
```

4)spec/AppSpec.js :

```
var 
  request = require('supertest-as-promised'), // npm i --save-dev supertest-as-promised
  app = require('./../app');

var token = "some token here";

describe('App', function() {

  describe("Posts", function() {

    it('should pass auth check and get posts', function() {
      return request(app)
               .get('/posts')
               .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
               .expect(200);
    });

  });
});
```

p.s. I'm using `jasmine` as testing framework, but even with `mocha` it's same style. Because of it's using `supertest-as-promised` that gets app module and calls the route without creating http object.

p.s.2. it's not unit testing, You're testing the feature, so it's more an integration test to check if all chains of code is properly integrated.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate this response. Regarding that last p.s. Is there no way to add unit testing to something like this? I was looking for something to just test my logic independent of the server status and whatnot.

Comment: Change it as You want, You can require any element of Your code and check it's function.

Comment: I might have misunderstood something here but is there a way to mock out the passport authenticate? Right now I think I would need get a token and put that in for the token variable you have above.

Comment: If You're checking if route works it's enough to get some response. But to check passport auth You have to have some mock-ups, maybe some fake auth strategy that will replace local strategy. https://gist.github.com/mweibel/5219403